# How to change tf.keras to make _Merge class publicly available?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

In Tensorflow 1.14, I want to be able to inherit from the private `tf.keras` `_Merge` class to implement a custom `_Merge` layer in an external file.

Previously, in standalone Keras, I changed the content of the file `.../keras/layers/merge.py` by replacing all `_Merge` by `Merge`, e.g. from

```py
class _Merge(Layer):
(...)
class Add(_Merge):
```

to

```py
class Merge(Layer):
(...)
class Add(Merge):
```

Because I am now using a function of `tf` that calls upon `tf.keras`, I want to switch over from standalone Keras to `tf.keras`. I changed the same file in the same way. Additionally, I added the decorator to the `Merge` class, as was done for the classes inheriting from `_Merge` in `merge.py`.

```py
@keras_export('keras.layers.Merge')
class Merge(Layer):
```

Also I added

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.merge import Merge
```

to the `__init__.py` file, as was done for the other classes from `merge.py`.

However I still receive an import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Merge' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers' (unknown location)
```

I assume Tensorflow does some fancy exporting I don't know about, can someone explain to me which further steps I need to undertake to make `_Merge` accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge now, I think I need to recompile tensorflow after changing the source, as the exporting is used to automatically create the files from which everything is imported later on into python.